# How do we concisely define Eq based on a function?

Tags: haskell

We can use [`Data.Ord.comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) to write nicely concise `Ord` instances:

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
comparing p x y = compare (p x) (p y)

f :: b -> a

instance Ord a => Ord b where compare = comparing f
```

I would expect to find some similar function that would help to define `Eq` instances:

```
-- Does something like this exist?
equalityOn :: Eq a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Bool
equalityOn p a b = p a == p b

instance Eq a => Eq b where (==) = equalityOn f
```

Hoogle doesn't turn up anything with this signature, so I'm guessing this isn't a common way to define `Eq`. Obviously this is not a difficult problem to solve, but what is the idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way this is done is to reproduce your `equalityOn` function inline, using [`Data.Function.on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on), which has the type

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

This function generalizes `comparing`:

```
(.*.) `on` f = \x y -> f x .*. f y
```

(which is [literally the implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Function.html#on) from base).  Thus, we have `` comparing = (compare `on`) ``; `on` lifts any binary function by applying it to the results of a unary function.

So `equalityOn` is just `` ((==) `on`) ``, and your example instance becomes

```
import Data.Function

instance Eq A => Eq B where
  (==) = (==) `on` f
```

---

The proposal to add an `equating :: Eq a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Bool` (the more common name for your `equalityOn`) apparently comes up periodically; [here's an example thread from July 2014](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-July/023283.html).  The general consensus seems to be (repeatedly) that `` ((==) `on`) `` is preferable instead, although not necessarily by a huge margin.  Indeed, apparently `comparing` predates `on`, and I recall once seeing someone argue that if the library were designed today, we would have *neither* `comparing` nor `equating` and just use `on` everywhere!  But: your mileage may vary :-)  (I'm staying neutral here.)